# Intersection between rotated plane and volume sometimes fails

Tags: geometry-nodes, boolean-modifier, intersection

**I want to use geometry nodes to cut out the part of a 2D plane that lies inside a cube.**

As a minimal setup, I just added a plane to the exisiting default cube and scaled it up by 3:
[image]

When applying the follwing geometry nodes to the plane (simply adding a 'Mesh Boolean' node, setting it to 'Intersect' and combining the plane's geometry with that of the cube) I can get the intersection quite nicely. It even works when rotating the plane in the 3D Viewport (by pressing R or entering angles in the sidebar).

[image]

[image] [image]

However, for some rotation angles, the output geometry suddenly switches to a volume, consisting of the cutout of the plane and the part of the cube below it:

[image]

(The angles in this example are X: -23.5°, Y: -128°, Z: -104°.)

I assume this happens because boolean intersect is made for two volumes, not a volume and a plane. Indeed, adding some thickness to the plane seems to remove the issue.
However, I want to add further nodes to modify the cutout of the plane, and it having thickness really complicates that.

**Using geometry nodes, is there any simple workaround for this, without replacing the plane by a volume?**

I also tried adding 'Subdive Mesh' nodes to the geometry of the plane and/or the cube. This sometimes removes the issue for a specific angle, but it's never completely gone.

I'm running Blender version 3.4.1.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean modifier with different solver, "Fast":

[image]

Comment: Even the 'Fast' solver sometimes produces the effect, but at least more rarely, it seems. However, I would really prefer to do this completely in geometry nodes.